# How can I use the NVIDIA Optimus Graphic Card as Primary Card?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, laptop, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I'm checking around but I can't find an answer. I have an eeePC 1215N with Nvidia Optimus (Intel+Nvidia) Graphic Card. I'm not really interested in battery duration but more in performances. Ok, don't tell me to try bumblebee and vgaswitcheroo and all :) I did and have bumblebee installed and working. But I need a dual monitor configuration and gnome-shell+intel graphic card doesn't do the job. So the idea is to run the whole gnome-session on the nvidia graphic card but...how?!

Comment: Almost. The answers in the end just divert on how to setup bumblebee or ironhind or to not to buy NVIDIA Optimus laptop. Anyway some answers did the job.

Comment: If you want to use the properietary driver from nvidia and do not use hibernate/suspend, you may run your whole session on the nvidia card by starting the shell with optirun by editing the corresponding `/usr/share/xsessions/*` file. However, some programs do not like from being started through the virtualgl setup and may not run at all.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?